# issue with Angularjs 1.3 new controller as syntax and directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Till now I am using Angularjs 1.2 normal global controller syntax but now I need to move 1.3 and use the new controller as syntax and avoid global declarations as our requirements.

Now I am in the process of learning it. But some how I am failing to make it work even some simple basic application. Please find my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iQvOOW?p=preview).

Neither `<h2> {{ctrl1.item }}</h2>`  nor `{{$scope.subItem}}` from my directive are giving expected output. Can any one help me to fix plunker to out put item and sub item. And also can any provide me some good references to get familiar with this kind of new syntax using 1.3 and example tutorials, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plunker remove the `$curDir`

Try using the console in chrome or something next time. Got error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $curDirProvider <- $curDir <- mainCtrl

http://plnkr.co/edit/NrThd1?p=preview

As side note: if you see binding expressions `{{ }}` in your HTML then usually AngularJS has exploded with an error in the console output.

Problems with your directive:

a)

```
function postLink($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  // This is not valid JavaScript
  template : '<p> I am from New Directive with Item {{$scope.subItem}}</p>';
}
```

b) there is no javascript appending that template to the element. So you can't see anything until it does:

```
$element.append(template);
```

-- OR --

```
$element.append(angular.element(template));
```

c) there is no point using `controller` and `link` objects of a directive together - use one or the other is a good start point.

d) if you use `controller` then inside the directive body use binding expressions `{{ }}` to display data as you would normally. Also note, if you use controller as, make sure this is in you directive controller object:

```
function curDirective() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'mainCtrl as vm' // <-- see here
  };
}
```

Fixed:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AGB5bp?p=preview

Comment: But it is not displaying sub items from my directive. Any fix for that?

Comment: Well, there is, but you need to rewrite your directive.

Comment: Thanks @Callum, but unable to understand why I could not able to inject $curDir in to the controller? For this  curController.$inject = ["$attrs","$curDir","$timeout"]; to make valid, what I need to do ($curDir injected)?

Comment: what is `$curDir` where is it defined?

Comment: Sorry It was service which I missed here. Your sample code has clarified my doubts.